# Apply an Angular directive only after data is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive applied to a table, the outer div has a controller applied to it:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <table ng-mydirective>
        ...
    </table>

</div>
```

The controller loads some data and then uses `ng-repeat` to create some rows/columns in the table.

This is fine so far.

The directive needs to access columns possibly generated by the data, but the directive runs before the controller.

Is it possible to run a directive after the data is loaded/rendered? Or is the only way to achieve this by using $watch on the dom of the table?

Comment: Pass a variable into your directive and watch that.

Answer (score 3):

```
<table ng-show="myDataSource.length>0" ng-mydirective>
        ...
</table>
```

or how about applying that within your directive's template itself, i.e hide the table until after the data source is populated. But in both cases the problem is that what if you display a table whose query returned 0 results? That means you directive won't show at all. Either way the best way to handle this would be inside the directive. I.e. hide the table unless your `$http` call executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If your directive isn't using an isolate scope, it will automatically receive access to the data member in the controller scope.  If you reference that data member in the template, Angular automatically sets up a $watch on it and you don't have to do anything else; otherwise you will need to add your own $watch.  If you're using an isolate scope then it's a little more complicated but a similar pattern holds.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways for doing this

Easy one is using ng-if for requested data field. For example

```
<table ng-mydirective ng-if="nameOfTheDataSource !== undefined">
 ...
</table>
```

Also you can send an attribute to the directive and watch it until data arrives. This is more complicated but seemless to the template level:

Template

```
<table ng-mydirective ng-model="nameOfTheDataSource">
 ...
</table>
```

Directive

```
angular.module(....)
   .directive('ng-mydirective', function() {
       return{
            scope: {
               ....
               ngModel: '='
            }
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
               var firstload = scope.$watch('ngModel', function(value) {

                   if (scope.ngModel !== undefined) {
                       // Do what is needed
                   }
                   // Deregister itself
                   firstload();
                }
            }
       } 
   }
```